# how to save and restore tf.estimator model

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I would like to save and restor my tf.estimator model. Although I tried to follow other related issues on stackoverflow, I could not be successful.   The following input_fn can provide the data to be predicted. But I do not know how to use it to save and restore the model to predict. 
Btw, my return dataset has a shape of **[batch_size, dim]** where dtype is float32

```
def predict_input_fn(path, dim, batch_size):

    dataset = ds.get_dataset(path,
                             dim)

    dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size)
    dataset = dataset.prefetch(1) 
    return dataset
```

What I have tried until so far is the following but it did not work as expected, could you please help me to save and restore such a model?

**Trial**

```
  def serving_input_receiver_fn():

        features = tf.placeholder(
            dtype=tf.float32, shape=[None, batch_size])

        fn = lambda x : precict_input_fn(path, dim, batch_size)

        mapped_fn = tf.map_fn(fn, features)
        return tf.estimator.export.ServingInputReceiver(mapped_fn, features)

    estimator.export_savedmodel(model_save_path, serving_input_receiver_fn)
```

**Error:**

```
Failed to convert object of type <class 'tensorflow.python.data.ops.dataset_ops.PrefetchDataset'> to Tensor. Contents: <PrefetchDataset shapes: (?, 1024), types: tf.float32>. Consider casting elements to a supported type
```

Comment: Why is there a `keras` tag attached? I can't see any Keras modules used.

Comment: Question has nothing to do with `keras` - kindly do not spam the tag (removed0

Comment: Keras module was not used but someone who utilizes Keras may have some ideas about this as well.